# Apache APR function apr_procattr_cmdtype_set confusion

Tags: c, apache

I've been following tutorials online on C coding, and the code is using the Apache APR library.
It uses the apr_proc_t structure to execute an external app.
I'm confused about this function, could someone explain what this function means:

```
apr_status_t apr_procattr_cmdtype_set   (   apr_procattr_t *    attr,
        apr_cmdtype_e   cmd 
    )       

Set what type of command the child process will call.

Parameters:
    attr    The procattr we care about.
    cmd The type of command. One of:

                APR_SHELLCMD     --  Anything that the shell can handle
                APR_PROGRAM      --  Executable program   (default) 
                APR_PROGRAM_ENV  --  Executable program, copy environment
                APR_PROGRAM_PATH --  Executable program on PATH, copy env
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apr_procattr_cmdtype_set` function is used to tell APR how you want to execute the external command, it probably just sets an internal flag and does a bit of bookkeeping.

Let us look at the [`enum apr_cmdtype_e`](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/0.9/group__apr__thread__proc.html#gdcb981d7748c580eb69ac11dbf709060):

> `APR_SHELLCMD`
>   use the shell to invoke the program
>
> `APR_PROGRAM`
>   invoke the program directly, no copied env
>
> `APR_PROGRAM_ENV`
>   invoke the program, replicating our environment
>
> `APR_PROGRAM_PATH`
>   find program on PATH, use our environment
>
> `APR_SHELLCMD_ENV`
>   use the shell to invoke the program, replicating our environment

The first and last options (`APR_SHELLCMD` and `APR_SHELLCMD_ENV`) pretty much say "use a portable version of [`system`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html)" (with or without copying the current environment variables to the new process). The others are just variations on the Unix [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html)/[`exec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) pair with the flag choosing which of the `exec` family of functions to use.